# How to find an old file?

Tags: images

I'm looking for an image file that used to be this:

http://image.bayimg.com/gamelaabo.jpg

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly no. The file you pointed to is showing a 403 and unless you can contact the owner of the site to make it available again, you can never retrieve the image.

However, if you do encounter such events again, you can try doing the following:

1. Go to the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org) and enter the exact URL you would like to retrieve. This is a good idea to do if the file has already been made available for quite some time.
2. If you still cannot get the file you want, you can try going to [Google Search](http://www.google.com) and adding the "cache:" in front of the URL to the desired file. (i.e. search for "cache:http://image.bayimg.com/gamelaabo.jpg" in your above example)

Hope this helps in your future digging!

Comment: Actually I found it. Thank you for the answer.